# Regex to match numbers inside a text

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text file having numbers like this `+12345678912` (start with + and is 11 digit long) separated by tab whitespaces (seems like) in a text among with other data.

How can I match only those who have a `+` before the text and match the first 11 characters if they're present and they're all digits?

Updated:

This is the input

```
+12345678912    http://google.com   2012-05-07 11:30:06
+12345678913    http://google.com   2012-05-07 19:26:21
```

And the output should be an array with matching results

```
[12345678912, 12345678913]
```

Comment: Please give a sample input and what you expect as an output.

Comment: @Martin I've updated my code to suit your example output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this...

```
matches = str.scan(/^\+(\d{11})/m).flatten!;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/EIFNFIUz).

Comment: That returns nil.
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :526 > file2 = file.scan(/\b\+(\d{11})\b/).flatten!
 => nil

Comment: @Martin Drop the word boundaries.